# Is it okay to place selenium and appium classes to src/main/java package or in src/test/java

Tags: selenium, appium

We are creating a Selenium and Appium project in eclipse.

I was wondering if there are rules or right practices or correct location for Selenium and Appium classes?
During our training on Selenium, I notice that location of classes are in src/main/java.
While in our training on Appium the location of classes are in src/test/java.

Is it also okay to put the Selenium classes src/test/java?
Will there be any problem?

Or is it also okay to put Appium classes in src/main/java?
Will there be any problem?

What will be the best practice for locations of Selenium and Appium classes?

FYI, there will be no other code for the application. Just the Selenium and Appium classes.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Q. Is it also okay to put the `Selenium classes src/test/java`? Will there be any problem?

Ans: Yes it's absolutely fine, if you entire project is meant for `test automation`. There won't be any issue.

Q. Or is it also okay to put Appium classes in src/main/java? Will there be any problem?

Ans : Answer is again `No`

Since you've mentioned

> there will be no other code for the application

It really does not matter if you keep your code in any one of the folders

[image]

Since It's a Maven project, main/java is for development and test/java is for unit test. Nothing more nothing less, it's all up to you to decide which one to go for.

Cause if you are using **TestNg**, in `xml` you would have to give the full file path in order to run the class file, so it does not really matter.